# How to make cruisecontrol only build one project at a time

Tags: build-automation, cruisecontrol.net

I have just set up cruise control.net on our build server, and I am unable to find a setting to tell it to only build one project at a time.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using CruiseControl 1.3 or later you can use an [Integration Queue](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Integration+Queues)
These allow you to control which projects can be built concurrently and which must be serialized.